# For loop through a file - multiple conditions

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, awk

I got a file with two columns and want to write a for loop in bash which takes the value from the first column, subtracts 3 and multiplies it by the corresponding value in the second column.
And then add all the values together.

The file looks for example like this:

```
1  3
2  5
7  8
4  30
```

then I want a loop which does:

```
1-3 * 3
+ 2-3*5
+ 7-3*8
+ 4-3*30
```

I have already a for loop which looks like this:

```
 for ( p in $( awk '{ print $1; }' file.txt ) 

 do

   total=$(echo $total+($p-3) | bc )
   ((count++))
 done

  echo " $total" | bc > file2.txt
```

This works. But what can I do to include a multiplication with another column of the file?

The following idea doesn't work:

```
for ( p in $( awk '{ print $1; }' file.txt ) && k in $( awk '{ print $2; }'       file.txt )).
```

Comment: `awk '{ total += ($1 - 3) * $2 } END { print total }' file.txt`

Comment: if you don't use parenthesis, the explanation doesn't match the computation...  `(1-3)*3 != 1-3*3`

Comment: Yeah of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ sum += $2*($1-3); } END{ print sum; }' <input file>
```

Comment: Thank you!! But what can I do to go for more complicated iterations like integrals. If I want to multiply xi+1  -xi   *  yi.

Comment: I mean that I need to work more on the column. Could I do something that keeps my version of the foor loop but includes another condition?

Comment: Sure, just add another command to the awk script.  Your version of the loop is really not a good way to go.  These type of problems are what awk is designed to handle.   https://edm00se.io/assets/images/post_images/right-tool-for-job-jekyll/scottySays.jpg

Comment: ok I understand :D  so how can I take the value of a specific line in $2 and the line BEFORE and put the result in one line in the output?

Comment: `{ result = prev + $2; printf result; prev = $2 }`

Comment: Is this valid: `awk '{result = (sum += (prev + $2)/2 *$3); printf result; prev= $2 }`

Comment: Maybe....?  But with that, just have `awk '{ sum += (prev + $2)/2 * $3 ; printf sum; prev= $2 }'`  (No reason to set `result`.)

Comment: I could not make this work,I just wrote `awk  '{ sum += $3; print sum }'  input.txt > output.txt ` And in the outputfile there should only be one value, but there are still as many as in the input file but also altered to strange values

Comment: Are you using the same input file as above (you don't have a $3)?

Comment: No its another file with three columns. And replace print with printf just doest that the values are in a line instead a column

Answer (score 0):

You have been given perfectly valid `awk` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44526259/2989411). But if you prefer to use `bash`, as long as you operate only in integer numbers, you can do everything in `bash`, without need to spawn `awk` or `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
while read a b; do
    ((sum=sum+(a-3)*b))
done < file.txt
echo $sum
```

Comment: should be `(a-3)*b`

Comment: @karakfa Right. I've looked at example instead of description. Fixed.